# Does OWin support WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, owin

I have a c# project that exposes services via WebApi and also via WCF. It works under IIS.
Now I need to offer it as self host solution.
I cannot find documentation about Owin and how to expose WCF services.
Does OWin support WCF?

Answer (score 3):

I think the question should be the other way around. Does WCF support OWIN?

As I understand, OWIN offers the infrastructure needed to abstract away the web server. However, whatever framework you want to use on it must have an OWIN implementation, which I **think** WCF does not.

Nonetheless, you can still offer a self hosted application using OWIN or WebApi SelfHost for WebApi combining with a Self Hosted solution for the WCF as described in the documentation for WCF -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee939340.aspx

Answer (score 3):

WCF is not supported on OWIN at this point of time. [Owin.org](http://owin.org/#projects) > Projects has information on the supported frameworks on OWIN.

Comment: Note that OWIN.org is not maintained or monitored any more.