# 'Skipping' the IIS pipeline on A WCF web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

I've read [an article](http://www.haneycodes.net/to-node-js-or-not-to-node-js/) that states the following:

> IIS tacks on a significant amount of performance overhead due to things like session state management, forms authentication, the process model, request lifecycle events, etc. These are not bad things to have and use, but if you don’t need IIS, session state, forms auth, request lifecycle events, or the process model, then don’t use them!

Now it says to simply 'skip' these features, however i failed to find that information online and was hoping someone here could shed some light on the matter.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skipping IIS would involve OWIN/Katana project. There's no real template for this, but the idea would be to have the web application 'self-host' wcf, with the resolution going through OWIN's `IDictionary<string,object>` state dictionary instead of the normal IIS `HttpContext` object.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198935/does-owin-support-wcf) some more on this.

And here's a [starting point for coding](http://www.forkcan.com/viewcode/394/Owin-WCF-Host). Note that the `WebOperationContext` is still being used there, though.

Comment: As I understand OWIN/Katana is still in alpha/beta stages, or is it production grade ready?

Comment: It's part of MVC 5 right now. It will be more refined in ASP.Net vNext, part of the next .Net Framework release.